What is the sum of Permutation Number$\sum_{i=0}^n P_{n}^i $？
Here is a problem of finding Sequence of general term formula：
$a_{1}=1$, and for all positive integers$n$, $a_{n+1}=na_{n}+1$
After calculation, it was found that
$$a_{n+1}=\sum_{i=0}^n P_{n}^i $$
in which $P_{n}^m=\frac{n!}{(n-m)!}$ and  $ P_{n}^0=1$
so I wonder What is the sum of Permutation Number$\sum_{i=0}^n P_{n}^i $？
Thanks

$~e^1 = 1 + 1 + \dfrac{1}{2!} + \dfrac{1}{3!} + \dfrac{1}{4!} + \cdots.~$
If you define $~S_n~$ as the partial sum of $~e^1,~$ where the last term is $~\dfrac{1}{n!},~$
then
$$\left[ ~\sum_{i = 0}^n \frac{n!}{i!} ~\right] = n! \times S_n.$$
I am unaware of any other elegant simplification.

What about $a_n=e, \Gamma (n,1)$ ?

@ClaudeLeibovici I confess my ignorance; I am not familiar with that syntax.  I am (superficially) aware of something called the gamma function, but it has been decades since I ever worked any exercises that involved that function.  Further, the syntax I have seen is $~\Gamma(x),~$ so I don't know how to decipher $~\Gamma(n,1).~$

This is the incomplete gamma function .
